# is there a useable "hair collition to emitter"-solution yet?

Tags: hair

does it is sutch a solution, and if it exists, do that collition-solution work with a computer that dont have more than 32 gb ram and not bigger graphic card than nvidia gforce 1070 with 2 gm ram inside, or not faster cpu than a amd ryzen 7 (8 core 16 tread) prosessor?

Comment: I believe the 1070 comes with 8gb of ram

Comment: ok, i forgot that. but i dont have the dual version.